# Invalid token on push from certain hosts

Tags: java, ios, apple-push-notifications

One of our Java apps keeps getting back "invalid token" when we try to send a push to APNS, but only on one host.

The same application on a different host sending to the same token using the same certificate can send successfully, and the mobile app receives the push.

We're using the `com.notnoop.apple:apns` library to send pushes.

Is there anything on the Apple side that might restrict push requests based on IP address?  If not, what else might cause something like this?

Comment: Most of the time, this kind of problems are certificate related, e.g. when sending a production token to a sandbox environment.

Comment: @lifeisfoo In this case, both hosts are using the same cert (verified by checksum) and both are sending to gateway.push.apple.com:2195.  The appID is also the same for both.

Comment: **1**. Do you have checked the [TroubleshootingPushNotifications]( https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG3) guide from apple? **2**. What version of the library are you using? **3**.Have you tried enabling logging for the library? **4**. All hosts are using the same version of the library? **5**. All hosts are using the same java version?